# What is the <select-window> key on the Apple extended keyboard?

Tags: key-bindings

[OS X 11.6, Emacs 25.1]

Using my Apple Extended Keyboard I just stumbled on an Emacs key called `<select-window>`. It is bound, naturally, to `select-window`. I discovered the key by  accidentally hitting it, seeing something happen, and checking what key I hit by viewing Lossage.

What key (possibly modified) is this?? I can't find it anywhere.